# jQuery .resize() only works when making the window bigger

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to resize the main content div #inhalt of my website so that it always fills all the space available. Basically I do this by setting a height of *total usable height* - *top position of #inhalt (pixels from top)* - *padding etc.*. This is my javascript/jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#inhalt").height($("#zentriert").height() - $("#inhalt").position().top - 48);
  $(window).resize(function() {
    $("#inhalt").height($("#zentriert").height() - $("#inhalt").position().top - 48);
  });      
});
```

This works fine when I resize the window so that it gets bigger. It doesn't, however, when I make it smaller.

Does anybody have an idea why and what I could do?

Comment: To get the space available, you should use `$(window).height()`.

Answer (score 1):

It does work fine for me. I have used it at plenty of places. You can check this by having a log message inside `resize` handler.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    console.log('window resized');
    $("#inhalt").height($("#zentriert").height() - $("#inhalt").position().top - 48);
});
```

Comment: Weird! This log message does show also when I resize it to a smaller size, but #inhalt doesn't resize!

Comment: @user1031178 - That means there is some issue in your logic. Try to debug and find it out.

Comment: ah, sorry, #zentriert increases whenever #inhalt increases, so when resizing to a smaller window, $("#zentriert").height() stays the same and so does #inhalt

Comment: Since you are controlling `#inhalt`'s height based on `#zentriert`'s height it will remain constant if the later do not change.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I am having the same problem.  I see the issue, but what is the solution?  How do you make the container smaller if it's full with the accordion?